# Is this proof of the limit of the product of a bounded function and a function that goes to zero correct?

Tags: limits, epsilon-delta

I have to learn a long list of proofs. In order to understand them I try to reformulate them and make them easier for me to grasp. In the process of doing so I often make them incorrect. I wonder if the following is correct?

**Prove that:** $$\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)g(x) = 0$$ if $$\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = 0$$ and $g(x)$ is bounded.

**Proof:** Since $g(x)$ is bounded $\exists M: |g(x)|< M$, and since $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)$ we have $$\forall \varepsilon > 0, \exists \delta: x > \delta \Rightarrow |f(x)| < \varepsilon.$$
We then get
$$|g(x)|< M \Rightarrow |f(x)g(x)| < |f(x)\cdot M|$$
and combine this with the limit definition
$$\forall \varepsilon > 0, \exists \delta: x > \delta \Rightarrow |f(x)| < \varepsilon \Leftrightarrow \varepsilon \cdot M > |f(x) \cdot M| > |f(x) g(x)|$$
q.e.d.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost. Here are some things that I would modify:

Let $\varepsilon >0$. Since ${\displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}}f(x)=0$, there exists $\delta >0$ such that $|f(x)|<\varepsilon/M$ whenever $x>\delta$. Assume $x>\delta$. Then $|f(x)g(x)|=|f(x)||g(x)|< |f(x)|M<(\varepsilon/M)M=\varepsilon$.

Comment: Ah, that looks good. Would you care to elaborate on _why_ you made those changes? I did my first epsilon-delta proof a month ago, so I am still very new to this.